# How to use ES6 multiple destructured arguments in function definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I want to know how to use destructured multiple arguments given to a function when both parameters are of same type.
For example, consider I have the following code:

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];
// sort by name
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

Now, as you can see, only the `name` properties of `a` and `b` objects have been used in the function. So how will I use [object destructuring](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/) to alter the code, something like this:

```
items.sort(({name}, {name}) => {
  // code to use
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign another name during destructuring:

```
items.sort(({name : A}, {name : B}) => 
  A.toUpperCase().localeCompare(B.toUpperCase())
);
```

(And you can use *localeCompare* instead of your if else logic)